# How can I make JavaFX re-initialize when Scene is swapped?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to make a very simple program in JavaFX. It goes like this:

The user inputs something into a TextField

The program displays the input on a label but on a *different Scene*

---

Here is my code:

Controller.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import javax.xml.soap.Text;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {

    //textField in sample.fxml
    @FXML
    TextField textField;

    //label in display.fxml
    @FXML
    Label label;

    String text;

    @FXML
    public void enter() throws IOException {
        text = textField.getText();

        Stage stage = (Stage) (textField).getScene().getWindow();

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("display.fxml"));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setTitle("Display");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));

        label.setText(text);
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

There are 2 other FXML files containing either a single textField or a single Label.

But whenever I run this code there is a NullPointerException signaling that **label** is null, because it hasn't been initialized. How do I fix this?

Comment: The best option is to maintain a one-to-one relationship between FXML files and controllers. In other words, don't try to share the same controller class with two different FXML files. Doing so makes it difficult to reason about what should be `null` and when. Note that when you load `display.fxml` a new and different instance of `Controller` is instantiated by the `FXMLLoader`. There are ways around that, but again I would suggest creating separate controller classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should make antoher controller for the display.fxml file (the other scene). Than in this new controller you can prepare a function to set label value:

**DisplayController.java**

```java
public class DisplayController {

    //label in display.fxml
    @FXML
    Label label;

    public void setLabelText(String s){
        label.setText(s);
    }
}
```

and in **Controller.java** edit `enter()` function by calling a new `DisplayController.java` instance:

```java
    @FXML
    public void enter() throws IOException {
        text = textField.getText();

        Stage stage = (Stage) (textField).getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("display.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        DisplayController dc = loader.getController();
        
        //here call function to set label text
        dc.setLabelText(text);

        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setTitle("Display");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));

    }
```